# How to subtract two cells if another cell has text of "Lost"?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Is it possible to subtract G4:G100 and H4:H100 if I:4:I100 equals "Lost"?

From G4 to G100 I have the amount set to currency as well as H4:H100.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: you mean H4:H100, right?

Comment: Yes, pardon my typo. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(G4:G), IF(I4:I="lost", G4:G-H4:H, ), ))
```

[image: 0]